# How to get inside Solaris zone and execute commands there by using Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, solaris, ansible-2.x

I have simple play book for Solaris

```
- name: root access test
  hosts: solaris
  serial: "10"
  tasks:
   - name: Make nfs mount on a remote server
     become: yes
     delegate_facts: True
     shell:  mount -F nfs -o vers=3,soft,timeo=10  10.0.0.2:/export/store /media/nas 
     args: 
      executable: /bin/bash
```

```
~# zoneadm  list -cv
  ID NAME             STATUS     PATH                           BRAND    IP    
   0 global           running    /                              ipkg     shared
   1 myzone             running    /rpool/zones/myzone              ipkg     excl
```

It working fine until you are in a global zone
But now I need to execute the same playbook inside Solaris zone 
I don't have direct access to the zone over ssh
I can only do:

1. ssh to solaris@box
2. solaris@box:~#  sudo su -
3. root@box:~#  zlogin  myzone
4. root@myzone:~#  mount -F nfs -overs=3,soft,timeo=10  10.0.0.2:/export/store /media/nas

Execute this command list inside a zone by using Ansible.
Anyone has any experience with zone working before?
Please share.

Comment: You appear to have root access to the system.  Just set up `sshd` in the zone and `ssh` directly to the zone's by its hostname or IP address.

Comment: yes that will be easy solution & in that case I will not post my question here on a forum.  The problem with that zone network it's  not routable.

Comment: So modify the zone's network configuration so it's routable, or give it a routable IP address.

Comment: Try zlogin's non-interactive mode. Become an administrator in the global zone and then run `zlogin myzone mount -F nfs -overs=3,soft,timeo=10 10.0.0.2:/export/store /media/nas`

Answer (score 0):

Create and Configure Zone in Solaris 11   create ansible playbook  step wise
"1. Create ZFS File system :  zfs create rpool/zone1  2.  Configure a new Zone zone1 : zonecfg -z zone1    3. Install Zone zone1    4. zoneadm -z zone1 install    5 . Boot the Zone :  zoneadm -z zone1 boot     6. Access Zone Console : zlogin -C zone1   a) System Configuration Tool  b) Set Computer Name : zone1   c)Network Configuration : net0  d) Network Configuration Method : static "

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).